# org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Cannot send, channel has already failed

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am using apache's activemq for queueing. We have started to see the following exception very often when writing things to the queue:

```
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: 
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.doOnewaySend(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:282)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.oneway(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:271)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.oneway(TransportFilter.java:85)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:104)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1366)
```

I can't figure out what could be causing this-- or even, frankly, where to start debugging what is causing this.

Here is the queue set up code:

```
    camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    camelContext.setErrorHandlerBuilder(new LoggingErrorHandlerBuilder());
    camelContext.getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT_SECONDS);

    routePolicy = new RoutePolicy();
    routePolicy.setCamelContext(camelContext);

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(queueUri);
    // use a pooled connection factory between the module and the queue
    pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    // how many connections should there be in the session pool?
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(this.maxConnections);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setMaximumActiveSessionPerConnection(this.maxActiveSessionPerConnection);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setCreateConnectionOnStartup(true);
    pooledConnectionFactory.setBlockIfSessionPoolIsFull(false);

    JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration(pooledConnectionFactory);
    jmsConfiguration.setDeliveryPersistent(false); // do not store a copy of the messages on the queue

    ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent(queueUri);
    activeMQComponent.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);
    camelContext.addComponent("activemq", activeMQComponent);
    Component activemq = camelContext.getComponent("activemq");

    // register endpoints for queues and topics
    Endpoint queueEndpoint = activemq.createEndpoint("activemq:queue:polaris.*");
    Endpoint topicEndpoint = activemq.createEndpoint("activemq:topic:polaris.*");
    producerTemplate = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();

    camelContext.start();
    queueEndpoint.start();
    topicEndpoint.start();
```

Like I said, the error doesn't suggest any directions for debugging, and it doesn't happen in 100% of cases where I can be sure my configuration is not set up correctly.

Comment: How did you create the camel route? Did you just use producerTemplate to send the message to queue?

Comment: If you drastically reduce the number of active sessions per connection, does the problem go away or occur less frequently? Are you sending messages at a fast rate or are there periods of inactivity? Have a look at the [inactivity monitor](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-inactivitymonitor.html).

Comment: I think you're onto something, @Ralf. I found a bunch of errors "max connections exceeded", so I up'd the max connection count and I haven't seen those errors since.

Comment: on local server Broker URL port in JMS-Configuration should be
61616 instead of 8161:
--> spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616

Answer (score 4):

- management port: 61616 (default)
- service port : 8161(default)

change your broker url port to 61616 and run

[refer this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/35035866589/)

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. You can open admin console at 8161 but you cannot send messages there.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I ran into the same problem. I found this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6600

Apache ActiveMQ client throws InactivityIOException when one of the jars is missing in classpath. In my case it was hawtbuf-1.11.jar. When I added this jar to classpath it started to work without errors.

Comment: How did you find out which jar was missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check, if there is a non-Jms client pinging your JMS broker. This may be an external monitoring tool, a load balancing tool such as [keepalived](https://serverfault.com/questions/550735/activemq-cannot-send-channel-has-already-failed-every-2-seconds.), or another one.

Comment: I don't see one. Thanks for the thought though!

Comment: @Denise How did you check this? You may change your port and see if the exception still occurs.